# Delphi RTTI dynamic cast

Tags: delphi

Let's say that I have:

```
type
 TClassA = class
  function prova: integer; virtual;
  function provaSuA: integer; virtual;
 end;

type
 TClassB = class(TClassA)
  function prova: integer; override;
  function provaSuB: integer; virtual;
 end;
```

Then I use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a: TClassA;
    b: TClassB;
begin
 Memo1.Clear;

 a := TClassB.Create;
 try

  b := ?? //dynamic_cast on C++

  Memo1.Lines.Add(a.prova.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(b.provaSuB.ToString);

 finally
  a.Free;
 end;

end;
```

I am using polymorphism and the static type of a is `TClassA` but the dynamic type is `TClassB`. Of course I can only call on `a` methods that are declared on `TClassA` (or that are overridden in `TClassB`).

If I want to use `a` and have access to ALL methods in TClassB in C++ I'd use a `dynamic_cast` that is (together with typeid) in C++ RTTI. How can I use Delphi's RTTI to do that?

Comment: You don't need RTTI on delphi for this. Just use the IS keyword in a if-then to check if the subtyping works and, if so, do the cast with the AS keyword! Do it like `if (a is TClassB) then b := (a as TClassB); else raise ...`. Don't mix Delphi RTTI with C++ RTTI.

Comment: `is` and `as` rely on Delphi RTTI, just as `dynamic_cast` relies on C++ RTTI. Also note that `as` performs the same type check that `is` does. The difference is that `is` returns a boolean, whereas `as` does an actual cast and raises an exception if a match is not found. So, if you use `is` first then `as` is redundant overhead, just use a normal type-cast instead: `if (a is TClassB) then b := TClassB(a);`, otherwise don't use `is` at all: `b := a as TClassB;`

Answer (score 0):

Delphi "RTTI" has a slightly different meaning from C++'s one. To replicate what `dynamic_cast` does, you need to follow one of the two patterns:

- pattern 1: *if the cast fails, I want an exception*: this is achieved, by using the `as` operator which performs the proper type-checking and then casts the object when possible. In case of failure, a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

  `b:= a as TClassB;`
- pattern 2: *if the cast fails, I want to handle it manually*: this is achieved by using the `is` operator which strictly performs the test about the cast. Then you are need to manually *cast* (look comments in code) on success:

  `if (a is TClassB) then
  begin
      // this is a cast, however, in this context, you are simply interpreting
      // the memory pointed by a as a class of type ClassB. You are not using any operator.
      b:= TClassB(a);
  end
  else
  begin
      // here you know that a cannot be cast to TClassB, therefore you can gracefully take
      // proper action here, without catching any exception
  end;`